# WebView Error : Connection reset by server

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

After running my JavaFX application it throws an error while the `WebView` is loading this **URL** : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

```
java.lang.Throwable: Connection reset by server
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1436)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1375)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1253)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1240)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2400)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2244)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:862)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFail$97(URLLoader.java:845)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It worked in my other **PC** but not in my current **PC**. Why? Is this a configuration issue? Im using **Windows 10** and my other PC is using **Windows 7**. What do you think is the cause of the **error**?